# Use javascript to unhide cursor when users are typing

Tags: javascript

Browsers today will automatically hide the cursor when detecting typing.

This is a probability when I set up keyboard shortcut on my web applications.

The cursor is hidden after users press any key on the keyboard - and only become visible after they move the mouse around.

This is a big problem to shortcuts that meant to trigger while some elements are being hovered.

I've noticed Gmail effectively unhides the cursor when typing keyboard shortcuts on the keyboard (you will see a blink).

Does anyone know how it was done?

Comment: Actually even on gmail the keyboard shortcut trigger the browser to hide the cursor unless there is an ajax load. It was not really the javascript unhide the cursor...but I like to know how to get this done as well.

Comment: @JamesWayne that is true. Interesting. Perhaps DOM change will prevent cursor from hiding.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. It's not ajax load but rather the fact the text area losing focus. If it's merely the DOM change then going to inbox would also unhide the cursor.

Comment: @JamesWayne I don't think it's either. I just checked gmail again and it looks like it doesn't unhide mouse at all this time when I checked. I suspect we can create a mouse move event once the keypress is detected.